# Deleting a "shop" object as a "user" object admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two classes of users: "users" and "shops".  I want the admin to be a "user" and be able to delete shops, and am running in to trouble.

I was able to get the delete button to show up in `shops/index.html.erb` if the logged in user was an admin (shown below), but when I try to delete a shop object I get the error `The action 'destroy' could not be found for ShopsController`

shops/index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All shops') %>
<h1>All Shops</h1>

<ul class="center hero-unit col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 shops">
  <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
    <li>
      <div class= "shop-name pull-left">
      <%= link_to shop.name, shop %>
        <% if current_user.admin? && !current_shop?(shop) %>
        | <%= link_to "(Delete Shop)", shop, method: :delete,
                                      data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class= "shop-address pull-right">
      <p><%= shop.address %> <br> <%= shop.city %>, <%= shop.state %> <%= shop.zip %> <br> <%= shop.phone %></p>
      </div>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The destroy action is in the shops controller though:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_shop, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: :destroy
  before_action :correct_shop, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index
      @shops = Shop.all
    end

    def show
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @shop = Shop.new
    end

    def create
      @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
      if @shop.save
        shop_log_in @shop
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up, welcome to ensage!"
        redirect_to shop_home_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
      if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @shop
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      Shop.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "Shop deleted"
      redirect_to shops_url
    end

    private

    def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(:name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :phone, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :picture)
    end

    def correct_shop
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_shop?(@shop)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

How can I allow an admin user to delete a shop?

Comment: can you please share full code of shops controller?

Comment: @Dabrorius done.  I tried changing the 4th line to `before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy` that didn't work

Comment: Well you have answers now :) Your destroy method is private.

Comment: It's asking me to log in as a shop now after I delete.  How can I delete when logged in as a user?

Comment: I have posted a suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your destroy method as private, so it is not accessible.

```
before_action :logged_in_shop, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

You probably want to remove :destroy from here, or it will expect that you are logged in as shop in order to destroy it. I'm not sure how your access control works but be careful not to make this publicly accessible.

Comment: That line is already included in the shops controller line 2.  I need for the user to destroy the shop, as only one user will be an admin.

Comment: Did you try changing that line to this? before_action :logged_in_shop, only: [:edit, :update]

Comment: Doing this along with adding `before_action :logged_in_user, only: :destroy` and `before_action : admin_user, only: :destroy`.  Not sure if any of my changes will cause problems in other areas, it is working for now though.

Comment: Yeah, we are getting into stuff that is very specific to your application and we can't see the code. I'm afraid we won't be able to help you out more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You have put action `destroy` in `private` section, this is why it is invisible. Try moving it up over `private` keyword

Answer (score 0):

First move `destroy` action out of private, secondly I cannot see `admin_shop`   method anywhere, either remove this line or define `admin_shop` method

```
before_action :admin_shop, only: :destroy
```

To add `admin_shop` method

```
def admin_shop
  unless current_user.admin?
    flash[:error] = "Not authorized"
    redirect_to shops_url
  end    
end
```

In your `destroy` action

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(current_user.id)
  Shop.find(params[:id]).destroy
  sign_in user, bypass: true
  flash[:success] = "Shop deleted"
  redirect_to shops_url
end
```

Comment: That line is line 4 in the shop controller.  But I need admin_user to be able to destroy shops

Comment: Thats good, but I cannot see `admin_shop` method anywhere, where have you defined it?

Comment: There will not be an admin_shop, the code needs to be edited so that only users are admins.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a `admin_shop` filter, you can use that, put it under private

Comment: I added that too.  The updated shops controller should be above.

Comment: But I need for the user to destroy the shop.  There will be an admin user, not an admin shop.  It is asking me to log in as a shop after I hit delete, which will then check if I'm an admin shop.  How can I make it so that the user can delete the shop?

Comment: add `sign_in current_user, bypass: true` before redirect and tell me if it is working or not

Comment: It is working now with the edits I made above.  I defined admin_shop in private and changed the before_login lines at the top.